# "Unidentified columns selected"

Tags: r, random-forest

I ran this code through RStudio and I received no errors:

```
rf.train.1 <- data.combined[1:891, c("Pclass", "Title")]
rf.label <- as.factor(train$Survived)

rf.1 <- randomForest(x = rf.train.1, y = rf.label, importance = TRUE, ntree = 1000)
```

However, when I try to do the same with a new variable it does not work and I receive an error stating that there are `unidentified columns selected`:

```
rf.train.2 <- data.combined[1:891, c("Pclass", "Title", "Sibsp")]
```

How can I stop receiving this error?

Comment: Check if you actually have a column called "Sibsp" in your data frame "data.combined".

Comment: I do - it's a factor but when I use 'ncol' it returns null. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I've realised the error that I made - it was a typo. Thanks for your help!